# Given the properties of the first and second order derivatives of functions, and proving the relevant inequalities.

Tags: analysis

Known $ \ 0<a<b,f(a)=0, and $ $\ f^{'}(x)>0,f^{''}(x)<0$  are true when $x\in (a,b)$. Please prove:$$f^{'}(x)+2xf^{''}(x)\le0,x \in (a,b)$$
We find $f(x)=x^{1/2}-1,x\in (1,2)$ meet conditions and conclusions. However, we do not prove the conclusion.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: This is false. Consider $f(x)=9x-x^2-8$ on $(a,b)=(1,2)$.